# How to implement a do while loop on a promise on angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite stuck in the development of an app right now. What i want to do is upon submission by ng-click the following task will be performed:

1. generate a 5 digit random number.
2. this random number will then be validated in the database if exist.
3. if it exist it will generate another number which will then be validated again until such time that the value returns to zero.

for number 1 i already have this:

```
  var gRandomNum = function(){
        var snumRand = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
        var numRand = snumRand.toString();
        var str_f = numRand.length;

        if(str_f == 1){
            str_final = "0000" + numRand;
        } else if(str_f == 2){
            str_final = "000" + numRand;
        } else if(str_f == 3){
            str_final = "00" + numRand;
        } else if(str_f == 4){
            str_final = "0" + numRand;
        } else {
            str_final = numRand;
        }
        return str_final;

  }
```

for number 2

```
var validataRandNum = function(pdata){
    return $http.get('api/cntTc/'+pdata).
              success(function(data){
                return data.tc_count;
              });
}
```

for number 3

```
do{
    var pdata = gRandomNum();
    var ifValid = validataRandNum(pdata);
} while(ifValid < 0);
```

Here is what it looks like on my Scope function

```
$scope.ok = function(){
    do{
        var pdata = gRandomNum();
        var ifValid = validataRandNum(pdata);
    } while(ifValid < 0);

}
```

When i tried to verify the value of ifValid all i'm getting is undefined but when i clicked again the value will show up but it was from the last clicked value. I tried to implement a promise but got stucked on how to implement it inside a promise. If you can provide a code that will do just that it will be great.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any way to move this to the server side?

To stick to doing this on the client, perhaps you can try to have validateRandNum() call itself recursively (but consider putting in some limits so it doesn't go on forever)...

```
var validataRandNum = function(getRandNumFunc, deferred){
    deferred = deferred || $q.defer();
    var pdata = getRandNumFunc();
    $http.get('api/cntTc/'+pdata).
              success(function(data){
                  if (data.tc_count < 0) {
                      validataRandNum(getRandNumFunc, deferred);
                  } else {
                      deferred.resolve(data.tc_count);
                  }
              });
    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.ok = function(){
    validataRandNum(gRandomNum).then(function (tc_count) {
        $scope.tc_count = tc_count;
    });
};
```